# How to convert Imagemagick's -morphology Erode Square into Rmagick?

Tags: imagemagick, rmagick, image-morphology

I have tried the following code in imagemagick:

```
convert input.jpg -morphology Erode Square output.jpg
```

I need to convert it into RMagick so that I can use in rails application

Comment: We checked in http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/optequiv.html but it doesn't have -morphology in it.

Comment: There seems to be an open PullRequest about this : https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/pull/40 maybe a comment there to show interests would be enough to make things move :)

Answer (score 1):

You can always write it using the `<<` operator:

```
MiniMagick::Tool::Convert.new do |convert|
  convert << 'input.jpg'
  convert << '-morphology' << 'Erode' << 'Square'
  convert << 'output.jpg'
end
```